# open external link without interrupting meta auto refresh

Tags: javascript, html, refresh

I have a very basic teamspeak viewer site that shows who is currently on.

I am using this auto refresh tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60;url=index.html">
```

I have a button that connects to the Teamspeak server that is clicked on:

```
<a href="ts3server://server.address?port=9999" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow">Connect To This TeamSpeak</a>
```

All work great, except for when I click the button that opens the windows application, the internet page stop refreshing every 60 seconds.

I am very new to all this, any help would greatly be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `target="_blank"` to your button's code which will make it open the link in a new tab and then transfer over to the Teamspeak application. This should prevent it from having any interference with the auto-refresh.

Comment: Thanks, this works, except is leaves a blank tab open over the original page.

Comment: Fixing the link and having the new tab auto-close is quite a bit more advanced, so hopefully this solution is suitable. You could try using JavaScript to refresh the page but it's not guaranteed to work as the TS3 link might be freezing the entire tab.

Comment: That should be the accepted answer because I have the exact same problem as OP and it's the solution to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out. I removed the html meta:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60;url=index.html">
```

and modified a Javascript code that I found from Philip M. 2010:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
/*author Philip M. 2010*/

var timeInSecs;
var ticker;

function startTimer(secs){
timeInSecs = parseInt(secs)-1;
ticker = setInterval("tick()",1000);   // every second
}

function tick() {
var secs = timeInSecs;
if (secs <5 ) {
document.getElementById("countdown").style.color = "red";  // and any other styling desired
}
if (secs>0) {
timeInSecs--;
}
else {
document.location.reload(true)
//clearInterval(ticker); // stop counting at zero
// startTimer(60);  // remove forward slashes in front of startTimer to repeat if required
}

document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = secs;
}

startTimer(60);  // 60 seconds 

</script>

<span id="countdown" style="font-weight: bold;">60</span>
```

The part I modified was:

```
else {
document.location.reload(true)
```

Now if I click the button to launch the external windows app, the page will still refresh every 60 seconds.